# Strip HTML from a query in PHP

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

Hi so this is a simple question and I have found other results and answers but I cant seem to figure out why it doesnt strip the HTML

I have a for each loop like this

```
foreach($allData[$counter]['comments'] as $comment) {

                $sentiment = SentimentAnalysis::decision($comment);

                      //store this in the DB to have access to the information at a later stage
                      RedditComments::create([
                        'comment' => strip_tags($comment),
                        'created' => date($allData[$counter]['created']),
                        'sentiment' => $sentiment,
                        'search_identifier' => $search_id,
                        'search_phrase' => $searchPhrase
                        ]);
                   }

            $counter ++;
        }
```

This stores each comment from an array into a DB using Laravel and eloquent.

But it is still storing my comments with these funny chartacters, my stored data looks like this

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Q:&lt;/strong&gt; Why do you think Apple is doing this? Do you really think they&amp;#39;re trying to hurt extension devs?&lt;/p&gt;
```

I want to escape these `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Q:&lt;/strong&gt;` before storing this

Comment: Looks like `$comment` is already like that before insertion, you need to investigate what's already encoding it. A wysiwyg editor? something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($comment))`